# When to use asynchronous computation?

Tags: java, asynchronous, nonblocking

I cam across below example on asynchronous computatiton:

```
//Create an Asynchronous channel. No connection has actually been established yet
 AsynchronousSocketChannel asynchronousSocketChannel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open(); 

 /**Connect to an actual server on the given port and address. 
    The operation returns a   type of Future, the basis of the all asynchronous operations in java. In this case, a Void is returned because nothing is returned after a successful socket connection
     */
 Void connect = asynchronousSocketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 5000)).get();


 //Allocate data structures to use to communicate over the wire
 ByteBuffer helloBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello !".getBytes()); 

 //Send the message

 Future<Integer> successfullyWritten=  asynchronousSocketChannel.write(helloBuffer);

  //Do some stuff here. The point here is that asynchronousSocketChannel.write() returns almost immediately, not waiting to actually finish writing the hello to the channel before returning control to the currently executing thread

 doSomethingElse();

 //now you can come back and check if it was all written (or not)

 System.out.println("Bytes written "+successfullyWritten.get());
```

I am new to asynchronous computing. But what I understand from the example given by you is that whole purpose of doing things asynchronously is to parallelize operations. As in case we had done things synchronously write() and doSomethingElse() would have happened serially. So the important properties for choosing asynchronous computation are:

1) doSomethingElse() should not be dependent on the output of write().

2) write() and doSomethingElse() both should be time consuming steps, else there is no point in parallelizing. Right?

Please correct me in case my understanding is wrong and there is something more that we are achieving by asynchronous steps in a computation.

Also could you please present a most common use case of using asynchronous computation.

Comment: Uh, asynchronous I/O and asynchronous computations don't necessarily pair together...

Comment: Yes,  you seem to have got the hang of it, because the Channel is asynchronous you can do something while it is writing data, the stuff you are doing in the meantime shouldn't rely on the result of the asynchronous task and indeed if it weren't time consuming you're just adding an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, basically you use asynchronous computation for time consuming tasks that should run in parallel to other tasks, e.g. ui threads. What "time consuming" means is a matter of definition though, i.e. in some systems it might mean "longer than a few ms".

As an example some "time consuming" task might block your ui top be updated so you'd run that task asynchronously, i.e. in parallel to the ui updates (e.g. in Swing this would mean using workers instead of doing those tasks in the event dispatch thread).

The availability of data is only a minor indicator of whether to use asynchronous or synchronous computation. You can defer execution of tasks until the required data is available (e.g. by using `Future` or messages) and still do other computations in the meantime (e.g. ui updates).

That said you should carefully think of how you model your tasks in order to reduce overhead (too many or too small tasks might actually reduce performance, unnecessarily block resources like CPU time etc.). If the availability of data essentially suggests synchronous computing, then that might be the way to go. Howver, you could still have multiple asynchonous/parallel processes each executing its own tasks synchronously.

Comment: I have another doubt and to explain it I shall present two scenarios:

Comment: 1) I have 10 files to copy to a file server for that I make 10 asynchronous calls each copying one file to the file server and I get 10 Future objects on which I can do get() to find out if jobs were successful or not. And if it takes 10 mins to copy one file, going asynchronous style I would be able to copy all 10 files in 10 mins (ignoring network limits etc). So that is a good use case for using asynchronous computation.

Comment: 2) Now I have just one file so it does not matter if I go asynchronous style or synchronous style, as I will have to wait for 10 mins anyhow and I am not saving any time so I would say go synchronous.

Comment: If you're really in the area of 10 minutes and _might_ have multiple parallel uploads I'd still go the asynchronous way because the overhead would be negligible in that case but you might benefit if you ever have more than one file. And I'd not provide both cases for simplicity reasons.